# Data returned null after calling function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

**What am trying to do :**

*am placing a payment-order in the payment gateway's server (using firebase functions).*

the `placeorder()` creates the order (this part works)

I want the details of the placed order's data back, and the `function(err,data)` has that data.
but everytime it returns null.

**What I tried :**

was pretty convinced that it was a problem based on `asynchronous execution`, tried rectifying it and this code is the result of it , still the data is being returned as **NULL**

```
 const functions = require("firebase-functions");

 
/* eslint-disable */

exports.order = functions.https.onCall( (amnt, context) => {
    
    var orderdata;
    const Ippopay = require('node-ippopay');
    var ippopay_instance = new Ippopay({
        public_key: 'pk_live_0WZhCNC5l7PJ',
        secret_key: 'my secret key',
      });
      
       async function placeorder(){
        ippopay_instance.createOrder({
            amount: amnt,
            currency: 'INR',
            payment_modes: "cc,dc,nb,upi",
            customer: {
                name: "Test",
                email: "test@gmail.com",
                phone: {
                    country_code: "91",
                    national_number: "9876543210"
                }
            }
        },
  
            function (err, data) {
  
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                orderdata= JSON.parse(data);
  
          }) ;
      }  
        async function orderdatareturn() {
            console.log('before promise call')
                  // Await for the placeorderdata() to complete
            let result =await placeorder();
            return result; 
        }; 
        return orderdatareturn();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is "promisify" the callback-style entry point for the ippopay api...

```
const Ippopay = require('node-ippopay');
const ippopay_instance = new Ippopay({
  public_key: 'public key',
  secret_key: 'secret key',
});


// call ippopay api to createOrder and resolve with the JSON result parsed
async function placeorder(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ippopay_instance.createOrder(params, (error, data) => {
      if (error) reject(error);
      else resolve(JSON.parse(data));
    })
  });
}
```

Now the exported function can be made simple and clear. The key is to await the promise resolution before returning...

```
exports.order = functions.https.onCall((amnt, context) => {
  const params = { amount: amnt, etc...}
  return await placeorder(params);
})
```

Comment: thanks ,ill check and update...and yea should've hid the secret_key...felt so dumb  :).

Comment: :-) I've done it before.  Best action is to see if the vendor lets you regenerate the keys.

Comment: haha lucky for people like me, they allow it.

Comment: to promisify you can use `util.promisify`  from `util` package