# Java script callback not synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, asynccallback

**What am trying to to do :**

*Placing a payment-order in payment gateway server and returning order details back to client*

using *firebase cloud functions*

the `Order()` does the asynchronous job and returns the order's data in `function(err,data)`

**What I tried :**

as you can see I tried to synchronize it using `callback` mechanism which doesn't seem to do the job. Still returning **null**.

**index.js code**

```
  const functions = require("firebase-functions");

 


/* eslint-disable */
exports.order = functions.https.onCall((amnt, context) => {
    
    var orderdata;
    const Ippopay = require('node-ippopay');
    var ippopay_instance = new Ippopay({
        public_key: 'pk_live_0WZhCNC5l7PJ',
        secret_key: 'secret ;) ',
      });
      
    function Order(callback){
     ippopay_instance.createOrder({
          amount: amnt,
          currency: 'DOLLAR',
          payment_modes: "cc,dc,nb",
          customer: {
              name: "Test",
              email: "test@gmail.com",
              phone: {
                  country_code: "63",
                  national_number: "5876543210"
              }
          }
      },

          function (err, data) {

            orderdata=data;
          });    
          callback(orderdata);
    }
    return Order(function(order) {
        //response.send(order);
        return orderdata;
    });   
});
```

Comment: Just move `callback(orderdata)` inside `function (err, data) {...}`. If you don't, the callback will run before the orderdata is populated.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work ..it should've, but it didn't

Comment: Then you need to debug it further..."doesn't work" does not give us any clue as to the precise nature of the problem. You need to investigate in more detail, line by line if necessary

Comment: I would have expected that `function (err, data) {
            callback(data);
          });` is actually all you would need. So maybe check you don't have any console errors, check that `data` actually contains what you expect, check the functions are definitely executing, etc etc.

Comment: You've asked this question 3 times now, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793912), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66894292) and now here. Looking at your latest code, you've ignored the advice given in those previous answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callback function inside `ippopay_instance.createOrder()` can return a value, but the code that calls the function won't pay attention to the return value.

I try to wrap your `ippopay_instance.createOrder()` in promise instead.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

/* eslint-disable */
exports.order = functions.https.onCall((amnt, context) => {
  const Ippopay = require("node-ippopay");
  const ippopay_instance = new Ippopay({
    public_key: "pk_live_0WZhCNC5l7PJ",
    secret_key: "secret ;) ",
  });
  const param = {
    amount: amnt,
    currency: "DOLLAR",
    payment_modes: "cc,dc,nb",
    customer: {
      name: "Test",
      email: "test@gmail.com",
      phone: {
        country_code: "63",
        national_number: "5876543210",
      },
    },
  };

  function getStuffAsync(param) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      ippopay_instance.createOrder(param, function (err, data) {
        if (err !== null) reject(err);
        else resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }

  return getStuffAsync(param);
});
```